# dot product of multiple vectors in R to optimize pokemon teams

Tags: r, vector, dot-product

My plan is to create a way to pick the best pokemon team. Im not sure how to create a list of all possible combinations of 12 vectors from the 16 defense vectors with the dot product of the 12 vectors and then do the same thing for the atk vectors. My other problem is finding a way to sum the Total value for the pokemon in each team. I want my results to look something like this matrix:

Team............TotalStats..............Atk Score...............................................Def Score

(6 pokemon)     (sum of stats of 6 pokemon) (dot product of each atk vector) (dot product of each def vector)

These vectors represent attack and defense interactions between each pokemon type

```
Normal.def=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Fire.def=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,.5,1,.5,2,.5,1,1,1,1)
Water.def=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,.5,.5,2,2,1,.5,1)
Electric.def=c(1,1,.5,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,.5,1,1,1)
Grass.def=c(1,1,2,2,.5,1,2,1,2,.5,.5,.5,1,2,1)
Ice.def=c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,.5,1)
Fighting.def=c(1,1,2,1,1,.5,.5,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1)
Poison.def=c(1,.5,1,.5,2,1,2,1,1,1,.5,1,2,1,1)
Ground.def=c(1,1,1,.5,1,.5,1,1,1,2,2,0,1,2,1)
Flying.def=c(1,.5,1,1,0,2,.5,1,1,1,.5,2,1,2,1)
Pyschic.def=c(1,.5,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,.5,1,1)
Bug.def=c(1,.5,2,2,.5,2,1,1,2,1,.5,1,1,1,1)
Rock.def=c(.5,2,.5,.5,2,1,1,1,.5,2,2,1,1,1,1)
Ghost.def=c(0,0,1,.5,1,1,.5,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Dragon.def=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,.5,.5,.5,.5,1,2,2)
Null.def=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

Normal.atk=c(1,1,1,1,1,.5,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Fire.atk=c(1,1,1,1,1,.5,2,1,.5,.5,2,1,1,2,.5)
Water.atk=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,.5,.5,1,1,1,.5)
Electric.atk=c(1,1,2,1,0,1,1,1,1,2,.5,.5,1,1,.5)
Grass.atk=c(1,1,.5,.5,2,2,.5,1,.5,2,.5,1,1,1,.5)
Ice.atk=c(1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,.5,2,1,1,.5,2)
Fighting.atk=c(2,1,.5,.5,1,2,.5,0,1,1,1,1,.5,2,1)
Poison.atk=c(1,1,1,.5,.5,.5,2,.5,1,1,2,1,1,1,1)
Ground.atk=c(1,1,0,2,1,2,.5,1,2,1,.5,2,1,1,1)
Flying.atk=c(1,2,1,1,1,.5,2,1,1,1,2,.5,1,1,1)
Pyschic.atk=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,.5,1,1)
Bug.atk=c(1,.5,.5,2,1,1,1,.5,.5,1,2,1,2,1,1)
Rock.atk=c(1,.5,2,1,.5,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1)
Ghost.atk=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1)
Dragon.atk=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2)
Null.atk=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

### Test data:

```
Number  Pokemon     Type_1   Type_2   Total
3       Venusaur    Grass    Poison   425
6       Charizard   Fire     Flying   425
9       Blastoise   Water    Null     425
12      Butterfree  Bug      Flying   305
15      Beedrill    Bug      Poison   305
18      Pidgeot     Normal   Flying   399
20      Raticate    Normal   Null     343
22      Fearow      Normal   Flying   381
```

Comment: OK, so what is the question?  Please delete everything except the piece of code (and the input data) where you are running into a problem.  Note that we are *not* going to suggest how well your algorithm succeeds in producing a winning team, just whether your code implements your algorithm correctly.

Comment: I do not care how well it works as long as it works! I have edited the post as you asked. Thanks!

Comment: Why do people post data with unneeded empty lines????

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?
Make your defense vectors into a matrix  by  using `defmat<-cbind(all_your_vectors)`

```
library(pracma)

defcomb <- combs(1:16,12) # there are 1820 such combinations

defdot <- vector()
for (j in 1:1820) defdot[j]<- defmat[,c(defcomb[j,])] %*%  defmat[,c(defcomb[j,])]
```

Where I dotted the subset with itself since it isn't clear what you want to do.

Comment: Each pokemon has 2 types. From these 2 types I can make a metric for their defense and attack based on how these types interact with the types of other pokemon. For example Venasaur is type grass and poison therefore to get his attack score I will take the dot product of grass.atk and poison.atk and then do the same thing with grass.def and poison.def.

A team will have 12 of these vectors, 2 from each pokemon. Say my team has the types grass,poison, fire,null,water,null,electric,null,psychic,null,normal,flying. Then the teams defense score would be the dot product of all those .def vectors.